# How to load resources from external assembly in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, uri

To create an Uri you usually do something like

```
Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Localization/Texts.en-GB.xaml");
```

From this you can for example create a ResourceDictionary..

```
ResourceDictionary dictionary = new ResourceDictionary();             
dictionary.Source = uri;
```

Now the question is how do i do the same with an assembly (embedded resources) ??

```
Assembly asmbly = Assembly.LoadFrom("this_is_in_another_place/texts.dll")
```

This dosn't work of course..

```
Uri uri = new Uri("/asmbly;component/Texts.en-GB.xaml");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i couldn't get it to work with Uri here is a solution that works.

```
 Assembly asmbly = Assembly.LoadFrom("this_is_in_another_place/texts.dll")

 ResourceDictionary dic;

 using (Stream s = asmbly.GetManifestResourceStream("Texts.en-GB.xaml"))
 {
    using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(s))
    {
        dic = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(reader);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I thought the same thing, using `GetManifestResourceStream`, but i was looking for a way to do with Uri...